# Multires modifier sculpt base mesh option disabled

Tags: sculpting

[image]

I am unable to select this option, I've tried multiple different solutions but nothing worked, including deleting/applying my existing modifiers besides this one, trying on a different mesh, trying on a different mesh on another file, and even updating blender :( i need to use this to create a high res version of the model underneath it to bake into a normal map without destroying the uv map, the other modifiers i have on this mesh are mirror, solidify, and armature

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

"Sculpt Base Mesh" apparently is enabled only while in sculpt mode (tested in 2.93.6).

(Edited)